# Is quantum turing machine equivalent classical turing machine?

Tags: quantum-computation

I have the question if quantum computation is intrinsecally different to a classic computation. Thank you all!!

Comment: see for example https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/230

Answer (score 6):

They are "equivalent" in the sense they compute the same functions. They are not "equivalent" in the stronger sense that the computation time is the same "up to polynomial" (while, say, Turing machine and Church lambda-calculus or Markov's algorithms are equivalent in this stronger sense).